# Javascript access to hardware?

Tags: javascript, security, browser

I work for a company that has web and mobile apps.  They are going to implement some changes to get a device ID from mobile AND web browser based system.  Looks like Javascript has some ability to get hardware info like motherboard serial number etc.  I was a bit shocked by this since I though my desktop browser was somewhat limited in this respect.

So, my question to this group is:

1. Is this true for WIN/MAC/Linux desktop systems running different browsers?
2. Anyway to block this and have some control over what unscrupulous vendors/agencies can strip mine from my system?

Comment: Really? Do you have any example code?

Comment: `Looks like Javascript has some ability to get hardware info like motherboard serial number etc` - that's complete nonsense. Can you show an example of what is in your user agent string?

Comment: I guess the deepest javascript-hardware hack on desktop machines is the `navigator` object, lol.

Comment: I don't see how w/o a plugin (ActiveX in Windows, anyway) which they'd have to consent to. In Chrome I can't even launch a system app, so I don't see how there either.

Comment: You *shouldn’t* be able to get any kind of unique hardware identifier from JavaScript — what information did you find about getting the motherboard serial number?

Comment: What browser does your company expect their clients to be using?

Comment: OP's possibly misunderstood this article: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/How-to-Use-JavaScript-for-Hardware-Knowledge/2/. It uses an ActiveX control to gather motherboard information.

Answer (score 6):

This is completely false.

*In-browser* Javascript (without the use of plugins) has no hardware access, and (I strongly assume) never will have.

Comment: I would +100 this if I could.

Comment: Well, technically `webGL` does have hardware access. I don't see a +100 on this answer.

Comment: That largely depends on the implementation of the browser. It cannot be completely false.

Comment: @namuol: No sane browser will grant hardware access.

Comment: Who said anything about *sane* browsers? It's totally possible to retrieve Motherboard Serial number info from VB which can be compiled into an ActiveX control capable of being executed in IE6. A plugin could be made to add JScript globals to access this info. It's naive to assume that everyone uses secure browsers.

Comment: @SLaks, see my answer below for an example.

Comment: Javascript at its core, and ALL SOFTWARE, can only exist by "accessing hardware" almost always indirectly. I think this answer means "direct and unrestricted access" to hardware - which not even native programs have. So I think this answer is written with black and white thinking, where reality is always shades of gray.

Answer (score 5):

In general, browser makers (such as Microsoft's IE, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, etc) do not supply JavaScript mechanisms for accessing specific hardware information.

However, in some browsers (especially "legacy" browsers such as IE6) the use of ActiveX, plugins, Java Applets, or even specific browser exploits can reveal this kind of information by executing code outside of the secure confines of the browser. What platform does your employer expect this information to be retrieved from?

Here's an example using ActiveX through JavaScript.

I have personally tested this code in IE8. It correctly displays motherboard information, including serial number. IE8 prompts me to allow the script to run, but an older version or poorly-configured version may run the script unconditionally. ([Original Source](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/How-to-Use-JavaScript-for-Hardware-Knowledge/2/)):

```
var locator = new ActiveXObject ("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
var service = locator.ConnectServer(".");
var properties = service.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard");
var e = new Enumerator (properties);
document.write("<table border=1>");
for (;!e.atEnd();e.moveNext ())
{
      var p = e.item ();
      document.write("<tr>");
      document.write("<td>" + p.HostingBoard + "</td>");
      document.write("<td>" + p.Manufacturer + "</td>");
      document.write("<td>" + p.PoweredOn + "</td>");
      document.write("<td>" + p.Product + "</td>");
      document.write("<td>" + p.SerialNumber + "</td>");
      document.write("<td>" + p.Version + "</td>");
      document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

---

To prevent this from happening to your machine, use a modern browser (IE9, FF4+, Chrome) and always keep it up to date. Additionally, be mindful of what plugins you install and more importantly, *where* you install them from.

Comment: I never said the sky is falling. I'm trying to illustrate that it's not out of the question. And as of [August 2011, about 18% of the browser market share is running IE8 or older](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp).

Answer (score 0):

1. No. Proof: FireFox, Chrome/Chromium, to name a few.
2. Don't worry. JavaScript won't get access to these resources

Comment: FF and Chrome are safe, sure, but IE5.5-8 seem to be vulnerable to this specific problem via ActiveX. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score -2):

A browser cannot access hardware information.

There are other javascript tools like Titanium or node.js that may access hardware or any other information.

Comment: node.js is a server-side JavaScript environment, and Titanium compiles  JavaScript into native code for iOS and Android -- neither of these would give you access to client hardware information from a browser.